# Creating a 3-column layout that collapses to 2 column

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout with 3 columns when over 1440px, and two columns from 800px to 1440px - the media queries I've got are working fine, however the problem is trying to get the cols to align vertically:

[Screen shot http://pichut.eu/x/Screen_Shot_2013-10-13_at_10.png](http://pichut.eu/x/Screen_Shot_2013-10-13_at_10.png)

As you can see the third col when collapsed aligns left, however it sits bellow the end of the first column, but I would prefer if it were aligned with the bottom of the first! (make sense? :L)

Here's the HTML for the cols:

```
<div class="dyn-col">
    <div class="widget">
       <div class="widget-title">
            Widget Title
        </div>
        <div class="widget-content">
            Widget Contents
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dyn-col">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-title">
            Widget Title
        </div>
        <div class="widget-content">
            Widget Contents
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dyn-col">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-title">
            Widget Title
        </div>
        <div class="widget-content">
            Widget Contents
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS i've got for the page...

```
/*=================================================
Dynamic Cols
=================================================*/
.dyn-col {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .dyn-col {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1439px) {
    .dyn-col {
        width: 50% !important;
        float: left;
    }

    .dyn-col:last-child {
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    .dyn-col {
        width: 33.3% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the css attribute clear: both; on the cols?

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend using bootstrap 3 makes life easier when doing stuff like that I use it alot.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, it's not very helpful to the OP.